# Table Functions and FLATTEN in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, flatten

Is it possible to use `FLATTEN` and `TABLE_QUERY` function together?

It looks like the `TABLE_QUERY` returns only the table name and `FLATTEN` requires the dataset as well.

**FROM Clause:**

```
FROM FLATTEN(TABLE_QUERY(nbr_pcrf, 'table_id CONTAINS "dump_"'), quotas) d
```

**Error:**

> Query Failed
>   Error: Table name cannot be resolved: dataset name is missing.
>   Job ID: nbr-data-storage:job_44jU_diWnh4tk27UxDxFP-I5Rbg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a little bit misleading: what is happening is that `FLATTEN()` with anything that isn't just a table name needs an extra set of parentheses to distinguish the field you're flattening by from a table. In other words, if you do

`SELECT ... FROM FLATTEN(TABLE_QUERY(...), foo)`

the `foo` field gets interpreted as a unioned table name (as in `SELECT * from bar,foo`).

The workaround for this issue is simple: Add another set of parentheses. That is:

```
SELECT ... FROM 
FLATTEN((TABLE_QUERY(nbr_pcrf, 'table_id CONTAINS "dump_"')), quotas)
```

Comment: No problem, I've tried to use CONCAT() but unfortunately it wasn't accepted, so I'll merge the tables in a single one. Does the bug tracker tool is public? Could you please provide me the URL? Thanks

Comment: The bug database the BigQuery team uses is not public, but there is a public issue tracker that you can use to report problems and check on their status. https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list

Comment: is it solved by now? I just had the same issue here and was wondering on how to solve it